# can i get dicom image from remote machine in ClearCanvas?

Tags: c#, .net, dicom, clearcanvas

can i get dicom image from remote machine via

```
EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://127.0.0.1:51124/ClearCanvas/ImageViewer/Automation?wsdl");" ?????
```

for example :

```
EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://MYIP:myport/ClearCanvas/ImageViewer/Automation?wsdl");
```

Comment: Such highly vendor specific questions don't usually work well in a general Q+A site like SO.  Use the vendor's support forum: http://www.clearcanvas.ca/dnn/Community/Forums/tabid/69/Default.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Only if there is a service endpoint with a matching configuration on the machine you're connecting to. IIRC, ClearCanvas only supports DICOM transfers, so without downloading the source and adding a listener to handle the request, this won't be possible.

This type of request ABSOLUTELY WILL NOT retrieve anything from a DICOM compliant server. In order to retrieve DICOM images from a true DICOM server, you'll need to perform a DIMSE C-GET or C-MOVE operation as defined in the DICOM standard.

Should you choose to implement a C-MOVE SCU, you will also need to implement a C-STORE SCP to receive the file(s). Using a C-GET SCU will not require the C-STORE SCP; however, many DICOM servers do not respond to C-GET requests.

I suggest looking at an open source library such as openDicom or mDCM to implement communication with ClearCanvas. ClearCanvas implements an early (and heavily modified) version of mDCM, but either will work. If you want to get more in depth, I HIGHLY recommend that you get the Springer book "Digital Imaging and Communications in Medicine (DICOM): A Practical Introduction and Survival Guide" by Oleg S. Pianykh.

Also, don't be discouraged at the start, the whole DICOM standard is a frightening beast and it takes some time to really get used to working with it.